# How does 30W adapter charge faster than 12W?

Tags: power-supply

One of the popular tablet company claims their product charges two times faster when used with 30W instead of 12W.

What is the relation between charge speed and Wattage of the adapter.

My confusion arises from the fact that imagine you have two 12V supply one with 30W and the other 12W. When you connect 10k Ohm load they will both supply the same current.

How come 30W adapter charges faster assuming it outputs the same voltage with 12W one?

Comment: A battery isn't a constant impedance load. The battery itself is has actually very low impedance, so there is charge controller that throttles the current

Comment: Are the 12W and 30W chargers connected to the tablet via a USB-C type connector? If so the USB-C has protocol to permit a charger to output higher voltages than just the legacy 5V of typical USB chargers. Some devices can take advantage of the higher voltage to permit charging their batteries faster.

Comment: @MichaelKaras it is called Lightning connector

Comment: Lightning connector would only be found on Apple products and Apple compatible chargers. USB-C connectors are different and are what my comment applies to. I cannot comment about the capabilities of Apple products.

Comment: Yes it is Apple product,

Comment: @MichaelKaras What you say also applies to lightning, I believe. Of course, the protocol/pinout is different, and we don't have many information because it is proprietary, but I recall every lightning charger (and even simple lightning to USB cables) embed a chip that can report the kind of charger it is, so the device knows how much it can draw.

Answer (score 3):

> How come 30W adapter charges faster assuming it outputs the same
>   voltage with 12W one?

This assumption is invalid. [Apple's 29W and 30W power adapters](https://www.hardwarezone.com.sg/tech-news-whats-difference-between-apples-new-30w-usb-c-adapter-and-old-29w-one) are based on USB Type-C technology with Power delivery options, and thus use a switch to elevated voltages in 30-W modes.

> - Apple 30W USB-C Power Adapter: 5V @ 3A, 9V @ 3A, 15V @ 2A, 20V @
>     1.5A
> - Apple 29W USB-C Power Adapter: 5.2V @ 2.4A, 14.5V @ 2A

For a "12W" power adapter, [Apple devices](https://gtrusted.com/how-the-apple-iphone-8-uses-usb-power-delivery-with-the-apple-29w-usb-c-power-adapter) pull the standard mode 5 V at 2.4 A. So the internal battery charger has limitations and charges at basic rate, maybe 2.5A internally (if a single battery cell is used), or it must be upconverted into 8.4 charging voltage if a two-cell bettery is used, with max charging current of less than 1 A (internally). So the charge time suffers.

For the 29/30-W adapter Apple devices start with the default 5V@2.4A mode, and then switch into enhanced 14.8 V at 2 A max mode after initiating Discover Identity, SVID's, and unstructured VDM's, the elements of USB Power Delivery protocol.

As result, the conversion from 14.8 V into 8.4 V  battery voltage can give you about 2.5 A of charging current, or twice as it can get from a 5V (12W) supply.

Answer (score 2):

It's not necessarily marketing hype.

Say you have a battery that *can* be charged at 30W/12V = **2.5A** (and allows it).

- If the charger can only provide 12W / 12V = **1A**, then a 1A charger
  will only provide....1A.
- Using the 2.5A charger will of course charge at **2.5A**.
- Using a 5A charger will not provide more than **2.5A**,
  because the battery circuit will not permit it.

The takeaway here is that more current will be provided by higher-wattage supplies, if and only if the battery circuitry allows it.

Comment: What kind of circuit model can be thought to understand this?

Comment: The target device is always responsible for max demand charge rate.  THe source is only responsible for limiting demand beyond it’s design capability with active current limiting or PTC protection.  The version of specific target and model is needed to make any specific claims.

Comment: But 30W is a 6A at 5V on USB and the gold plating will burn out lightning fast (pun intended) in well under a year of daily use if this were true.  I have already seen black pitted lightning pads from a 12W charger and Apple replace them them with a 10W charger and cable.on another iPad

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist - OP mentioned "12V supply". That's why I used 12V in my example. Where are you getting 5V USB from?

Comment: @atomant - Proper battery circuitry will monitor the voltage and current. If the current is too high, it will open the circuit. It may stay open, modulate it (switch open/close quickly) or simply add resistance. Either way, the current is limited to prevent safety risk, and stricter thresholds are used to lengthen the life of the cells. As for a model, I would look search for battery current limiting circuits.

Answer (score 1):

Charge rate is always controlled by target yet limited by source.  So without a specific example, it is a marketing hype.

However I use a “Blackweb” 60W USB hub knowing that most mobiles are either 10W or 12W

I have used an iOS battery graphing software to show the dV/dt is no better (maybe 5% steeper) than their new tiny 12W cube

However since I have not tested iMacs there may be some advantage

Comment: You made a test and compared 30W and 12Watt charge speeds for the iPad? Interesting if you didnt see much difference which is what they claim.

Comment: I’ll see if I can get a graph test posted tomorrow.  I have the latest  iPad std size 128GB flash